# Format for exceptions and errors from Yodlee REST Aggregation API

Tags: yodlee

What is the best way to catch exceptions in the response payload for API calls made to the Yodlee REST Aggregation API?

Historically speaking I've seen `{'Error' => [{'errorDetail' => 'some error message'}]}`, but I've also seen `{'errorOccured' => true, 'exceptionType' => 'some documented exception type', 'referenceCode' => ''}`.

The [documentation](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/login) suggests I can expect exceptionType, but I'd like to be sure. The API call I'm currently most concerned with is /login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are types of error code format which you can expect-

**JSON exception format 1:**
{
    "errorOccurred": "true",
    "exceptionType": "com.yodlee.core.SiteNotFoundException",
    "referenceCode": "_afe4ae60-68fe-4443-a721-d97a192e9455",
    "message": "Argument value not found: 164413432"
}

**JSON exception format 2** (Same as format 1, but "message" attribute is missing so considered as additional):
{
    "errorOccurred": "true",
    "exceptionType": "Exception Occurred",
    "referenceCode": "_5c4d1347-cb4a-4404-809b-57dbfabcf1db"
}

**JSON exception format 3:**
{
    "Error": [
        {
            "errorDetail": "No session ID found "
        }
    ]
}

**JSON exception format 4** (Same as format 3, but "errorDetail" attribute is missing so considered as additional):
{
    "Error": [
        null
    ]
}

**JSON exception format 5:**
{
    "errorDetail": "Token authentication failed for cobrand/user Invalid cobrand conversation credentials"
}

This will cover almost all the scenarios.

Comment: I am recently getting this type of error : {"errorOccurred"=>"true", "referenceCode"=>"_d0363d1f-3d4e-48ec-ba22-dab7306bf8ec"}
could you please help me to undetstand what does it means?

Comment: @bunty- Could you please send the request to the Yodlee support with respective details and they should be able to help you out. As without that its tough to explain what could be the reason for that error.

Comment: Hey, thnx for reply Apoorv. We have created ticket to Yodlee.